# A clean way to obtain an (analytic or numeric) solution for this integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

A friend and I have been looking at the crazy integral 
$$\iiiint \limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\exp\left[-(x-t)^2-(x-h)^2-(y+t)^2-(y-h)^2-10\right]\mathrm{d}V$$
and can't come up with a decent method on how to obtain a solution. ($x,y,t,h$ are all variables, not constants) Fubini's theorem would let it split into 4 integrals, but those aren't the cleanest either. I can't think of another method that will work (of course u-sub/parts, etc).

Could residue theorem/contour integration work? Fourier integral? Any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit -- changed $y-t$ to $y+t$**

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term

Comment: You need to find the $A_{i,j}$ and the $B_i$.

Comment: How is that used? I'm not sure where matrices work into this..

Comment: Also, I made a change, small but still there.

Comment: Expand it as a polynomial. $A_{i,i}$ are the coefficients of $x_i^2$ $2 A_{i,j}$ are the coefficients of $x_i x_j$. The linear part has coefficients $B_i$. The constant part is not a problem. You can take it out of the integral.

Comment: I don't know if the integral converges. You need to check that $A$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-t%29%5E2+%2B+%28x-h%29%5E2+%2B+%28y%2Bt%29%5E2+%2B+%28y-h%29%5E2&x=0&y=0

$$(x - t)^2 + (x - h)^2 + (y + t)^2 + (y - h)^2 =2 h^2 + 2 t^2 - 2 h x - 2 t x + 2 x^2 - 2 h y + 2 t y + 2 y^2$$

Therefore, if  $\vec x = (x,y,t, h)$, then
$$e^{-10} \int \exp{-\frac12 (\vec  x \cdot A \cdot \vec x)},$$

Where
$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 0 & -2 & -2 \\
 0 & 4 & 2 & -2 \\
 -2 & 2 & 4 & 0 \\
 -2 & -2 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

You can check that $A$ is positive definite. The result is
$$e^{-10}\sqrt{\frac{π^4}{\det A}} = e^{-10} \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

EDIT: The trick is that, if you have a quadratic form $q(\vec x)$ (a polynomial with every term of degree two $q(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = A_{1,1}x_1^2 + A_{1,2}x_1 x_2 + A_{2,2}x_2^2 + A_{1,3}x_1x_3 + \cdots$), and $q$ is positive definite ($q(\vec x)$ is always positive), then there is a linear change of variables $T$ that diagonalises $q$ (it converts it to $x_1^{\prime2}+x_2^{\prime2}+x_3^{\prime2}+\cdots x_n^{\prime2}$). You can prove that $dV = \frac{dV'}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}$. So

$$\int \exp{-q(\vec x)} dV = \int \exp{(-x_1^{\prime2}-x_2^{\prime2}-\cdots x_n^{\prime2})}\frac{dV'}{\sqrt{\det{A}}} =\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}
\int \exp{(-x_1^{\prime2})} dx_1 \int \exp{(-x_2^{\prime2})} dx_2 \cdots
\int \exp{(-x_n^{\prime2})} dx_n =\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}
\left(\int \exp{(-t^2)} dt \right)^n,
$$
which is the integral of the Gaussian function.

This integrals are actually very useful in probability theory when you want to study the distribution of correlated random variables.

Comment: Interesting, I'm getting $e^{-10}\frac{\pi}{2}$, and Wolfram Alpha, too - http://goo.gl/uazyMV

Comment: Sorry. I think I made a mistake when dividing by 2. But you got the point, right?

Comment: So we can reduce a quadruple integral into a single integral by this method? That's neat

Comment: Could you explain 2 things: how you found the entries of A in this case, and what you mean by $dV=\frac {dV'} {\sqrt {\det A }}$?

Comment: The entries are the coefficients of the polynomial. There is a factor of two for the mixed terms $x_i x_j$, because you get both $a_{i,j}$ and $a_{j,i}$.

Comment: For $ax^2 + by^2 + c xy$, the matrix is $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & \frac{c}{2} \\
 \frac{c}{2} & b \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: By $dV = \frac{dV'}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}$ I mean that the Jacobian of the linear transformation is $T$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{A}}}$.